# como resolver esa duda para guardar nombres y edades

Tags: c

Mi duda es como puedo leer nombres y edades en un vector o matriz.

solo llevo esto

```
#incude<stdio.h>
int main (){
  char f[15],c[15];
  int  b[20];
```

Comment: para guardar los nombres en un vector vas a necesitar un vector bidimensional char nombre[10][20]; una dimension para el identificador y otro para el numero de chars.

Comment: para leerlo solo usa scanf ("%s",&nombre[1]); puedes usar un for para iterar

Answer (score 1):

Para los nombres usa arreglos bidimensionales​.

```
nombre[10][15]; //Aquí se refiere a que tenemos 10 nombres o cadenas de 
                //caracteres de 15 caracteres cada uno.
```

puedes leerlo así:

```
scanf ("%s",&nombre[n]);
                  //n es la posición de cada nombre en el arreglo
```

Comment: Realmente no son cadenas de 15 caracteres... exactamente son de 14 caracteres, siempre debe considerarse una posición para el terminador de cadena **\0**